# GCP Load Balancer - Host and path rules not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a VM that has 3 applications hosted on it. All the apps are working fine with the VM's public IP and port (e.g. 34.44.55.66:{port})

1. React JS website 1 (port 3001)
2. React JS website 2 (port 3002)
3. Express JS API 1 (port 3003)

I now want to have all these behind a [Cloud Load Balancer](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google-cloud-platform/cloud-load-balancing). I've done the following for it.

- Created three backend services (one for each application)
- Created Host and Path rules as below
  [image]

The load balancer is created without any issues. However, **only the default path works fine**. Refer to the details below (consider the LB IP as 55.66.77.88).

- **55.66.77.88**: Website-1 opens without any issue (default path)
- **55.66.77.88/website-1**: Website-1 shows error messages in the browser console
  [image]
- **55.66.77.88/website-2**: Website-2 shows error messages in the browser console
  [image]
- **55.66.77.88/api-1**: API-1 shows an error message in the browser console

  `GET http://55.66.77.88/api-1 404 (Not Found)`

Whenever I map any of the above backend services with the default path, they work fine. However, they do not work as expected when the path is entered in the browser.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep in mind that, in your configuration, there isn't URL rewrite action. That means your request

```
55.66.77.88/website-1/index.html
```

will reach the backend on this path

```
# Backend bucket example
gs://my-bucket/website-1/index.html

# Instance group backend
<backend>/website-1/index.html

# Network Endpoint Group backend
<NEG>/website-1/index.html
```

The base path provided to the load balancer is forwarded. When you haven't additional path in the forward, it works (case of the root path `55.66.77.88/`)

You can override the behavior in the advanced mode, and you can define URL rewrite for each of your rules.

---

You can define rewrite rule like this in the console

- Click on advanced configuration
- Set up your default configuration (any domain, any path)
  [image]
- Then click on add host and path rule
- Put * in the host as you did
- Then click on the pencil of the path rule section to define the rule by default. Here again, select your backend by default. no special rewrite, it's the default path.
  [image]
- Now click on add path rule.
- Add your matching paths. And only / in the rewrite URL part (you can rewrite your host if the backend rely on the host name, but it doesn't seem your case)

[image]

Do this for all your backend and test it (let 3 - 5 minutes to propagate your update to the edge node)

Comment: I'm using a `Backend Service` and not a `Bucket`. Can you give an example of the changes I may have to make in the `rewrite` section of the Advance Mode?

Comment: Helps to clear the CDN cache too :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was stuck on this for a while until I read this!