# GCP Load balancer URL map routing all requests to default backend service, configuration appears correct based on docs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-url-maps

It seems to me no matter what/how I configure my url map, the default microservice will be the one serving the request.

I have 2 containers which are node + nestjs based applications.

1. Auth
2. Public

All the routes in public have no prefix, I'm testing the /featured endpoint on the public service and I have also set this as the default service.

All the routes in auth start with the "auth" path prefix and I'm testing /auth/test.

Both of these endpoints work in isolation or if I set each service as the default service.

However I can't get requests to be mapped correctly to any backend service except the default one.

I've configured the url map on the load balancer using the UI as follows:

[image]

Comment: How do you perform your GET request? And which HTTP error do you have? a 404? ON the backend serverless services, do you have logs entry that explain you the URL really called and the 404?

Comment: Facing same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hilariously have no idea how I got things working in the past, but now facing the same issue on another project and I'm only finding my own thread, which is quite hilarious.

Comment: this will solve your issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921120/gcp-load-balancer-host-and-path-rules-not-working)